# What happens when we a negative value in python's for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

```
x = 10
l = [1]
for i in range(x):
    # Modified v
    print("Row", i + 1, l)
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(l[0])
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])
    newlist.append(l[-1])
    l = newlist
```

I dont understand what happens when the index goes negative

Comment: what is the goal of this code? Where is the problem (=which line)? please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you give negative index, value at that index is returned. For list
a=[1,2,3]

we can say

```
value 1 is at index 0
value 2 is at index 1
value 3 is at index 2
```

or

```
value 3 is at index -1
value 2 is at index -2
value 1 is at index -3
```

If you go outside this range of indexes  which is in this case  negative 3 to positive three, you will get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For your code, second for block is never executed  and hence you are not seeing index error.

```
x = 10
l = [1]
for i in range(x):
  print("Row", i + 1, l)

newlist = []

newlist.append(l[0])


# Length l is 0,so below code inside for is never executed as range is empty
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])
    newlist.append(l[-1])
    l = newlist
```